Expo Go cannot open Development Build on Iphone
I ran the command npx expo run:ios to create a development build of my Expo app. The app automatically launches in a iOS simulator, and the Expo project appears in my Expo Go app.
However, clicking on the project in the Expo Go on my iPhone does not launch anything. Nothing happens on clicking it. Tried scanning the QR code that shows up in the terminal but there is an error message in the Camera app stating No usable data found.
Using the packages expo-dev-client@3.3.11, expo@50.0.17, and my Expo Go app is on client version 1017599 which supports SKDs 49, 50. Iphone is using iOS 17.4.1.
Bot the Macbook running the Expo server and the Iphone are on the same wifi network.
How do I launch the development build of my Expo app on my iPhone?

eas.json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 7.8.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}

